# VSCode isn't showing inline typescript errors

Tags: typescript, inline, deno

I have just installed Deno 1.9.2 and opened up a blank folder on my PC. I am following a tutorial on the basics of TypeScript. This is where my problem is.

```
const someFunc = (n: number) => {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    return "even"
  }
}

const value = someFunc(4)
value.substring(1)
```

At one point VSCode gives the teacher an inline warning on value saying `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` I've looked around and was told to change my VSCode *typescript.validate.enable* to true. I've done this and I've restarted VSCode multiple times. When I run my code with `deno run index.ts`, I get my error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not related to VSCode or Deno.
In the code you provided function `someFunc` has return type of `string | undefined`. My guess is that your `tsconfig.json` has `strictFunctionTypes: true`.

You can fix this error by:

Correctly handling all cases -

```js
const someFunc = (n: number) => {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    return 'even';
  }
  return ''
};
```

Or disabling `strictFunctionTypes` in your `tsconfig.json` -

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-deno-plugin",
        "enable": true, // default is `true`
        "importmap": "import_map.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Although I am not sure if Deno can work without `strictFunctionTypes`.

Comment: Thank you very much. With this little script, I am not using a tsconfig. I'm just trusting deno will handle it. Do you know if there is a tsconfig that deno looks at somewhere where deno is installed?

Comment: @NaeNate here is the [manual](https://deno.land/manual/typescript/configuration) I found. Looks like you can specify tsconfig location by using `config` option. Welcome to Stack Overflow community.